# make application running other apk inside themselves

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I've got a ready apk file (child).
I want to create other apk (box) with blank activity and run my 'child' within this box.I just need something like envelope.

I can't install these applications separately. I need a single installation file (envelope with child inside).

Is it possible?

Comment: You are trying to make a Framework then. Search for info about Android Frameworks or SDK's

Comment: "I can't install these applications separately" -- then do not create two APKs.

Comment: If you could just 'run' any apk file you could also download them from whatever sketchy address and run this external code on the users device. Obviously not something Android would want.